# Making a specific <select> option automatically check and disable check box in another form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple form for uploading a file. In the form, there's a dropdown  menu where you can choose a category for the file you're uploading. I also have another checkbox which is by default unchecked. How can I make it so that if the third  in the dropdown is selected, the checkbox is automatically checked and disabled? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ($('#selectboxid').val() === $('#selectboxid option:eq(2)').val()) {
    $('#checkboxid').prop('checked', 'checked').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else {
    $('#checkboxid').removeAttr('checked disabled');
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqzXZ/1/) of it in action.

***Updated:*** changed attr methods to prop as per @JohnStrickler's recommendation.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set flags on elements instead of .attr()

Answer (score 2):

Check on selection whether the selected index is 2 (aka the 3rd item).  Then update the corresponding checkbox you mentioned to check/disable based on the above.

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var check = this.selectedIndex === 2;

  $(':checkbox').prop({
    checked: check,
    disabled: check
  });
});
```

Comment: The `.select` event is for text selections. You should use `.change` instead.